Module could be found in debug mode in VS code but could not in build-in terminal
I have created a conda environment named "pino" by:
conda create -n pino

Then, I installed the python 3.8 and pytorch in pino.
I did activate pino in the build-in terminal by
conda activate pino

And the terminal has shown:
(pino) jipengcui inform %

To test whether the installaton of pytorch is successful, I created a python file named 'test.py':
import torch
print("done")

Then, I have tested it in 3 different ways.

Debug in VS code.
It worked and shown result: done
Test it in VS code build-in terminal(zsh) by run:

python3 run test.py

It didn't work and provided information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jipengcui/Documents/3_vs_code/physics_informed/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'


Test it in MacOS terminal(zsh) by run:

python3 test.py

It shown the result:done
The launch.json is:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Python File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}

And the setting.json is:
{
    "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [
        
        

    ],
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [],
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
    "python.condaPath": "/opt/anaconda3/envs/pino/share/man/man1/python3.1"
}


Why the code could run in original terminal and could not run in VS Build-in terminal? How to fix it? Please!


Hard to know without more debugging information. Check your VS Code Python interpreter (CTRL+SHIFT+P, then type "Python: Select Interpreter"). Make sure it matches with the environment that the terminal uses.

These articles might be helpful. Unable to Automatically Activate Virtual Environment in VSCode for Python, How do I automatically activate virtual environment in Visual Studio code?, Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Sounds like you have two different installations of Python on your computer.  VS Code is using one, and the terminal is using the other.

@Anerdw My debug mode could run so the interpreter in vs code might be correct. To my suprise, the code could run in the terminal in zsh could run but could not in VS code build-in terminal. I'm sorry I couldn't provide more information since I have not enough reputation.

@JohnGordon Yeah, I do have two different installation of python. Python in conda env base is 3.12 and in the pino is 3.8. My question is, if VS use one while teminal use the other, how it could run in terminal in zsh and could not in VS build-in terminal?

You can [edit] posts even at one reputation. Can you do so to include some more details about the exact problem you're facing and an [mre] (code, console input/output, etc)? It's hard to know what's going on with this amount of information.

Perhaps the contents of the launch.json used for debugging are different from the settings.json used for the terminal? Python debugging in VS Code Why not check both and include them in your question?

Hello, this may be because your vscode and the built-in terminal are not using the same environment. You can try using the command conda env list in the terminal to check the currently active environment. Use conda activate <env_name> to activate the specified environment. Then reinstall the module to make sure it's in the correct environment. You can also read the documentation for more details.

@Anerdw Thank you for your suggestion. I updated it. Hope these information could be helpful.

@kunif Thanks for you suggestion. I post the two files. Could you please check whether it is correct?

launch.json is so simple that you probably won't be able to tell the difference. For example, using this article as a reference, why not try running it in debug mode and in a terminal environment and check the differences in sys.version and sys.path? Location of global libraries for Python on Mac?, launch.json breaks debugging in VSCode, Unable to use python modules...

@kunif Thanks for your suggestion! I found the python version in debugging were different from the build in terminal. The debugging used the python version in conda envpino while the build-in terminal using the vscode defult python version. Could you please tell me how to change the one in terminal to make it same in debugging?

Hello, you can specify the path of the python version by modifying the shell configuration file. For example, modify a .bashrc or .zshrc file, usually it under /usr/local/bin/python3. Add export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH to the file. Once the file is closed, run the source ~/.zshrc application. You can then select an interpreter through Select Interpreter. See if this solves the problem.

Thank you all. The problem has been fixed refer to Common questions
-terminal profile. As depicted in the common question:

standalone macOS terminals all run as login shells by default, since macOS does not run a login shell when the user logs into the system.

Then, with "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false added to setting.json, the problem was fixed.
